# Does anyone know the nusach for אפפוני חבלי מות that is sung in the movie Simon Magus?

Tags: passover, tehilim-psalms, music, hallel, performance-entertainment

I haven't seen the whole movie Simon Magus. It depicts 19th-century Poland. I saw a scene where a Pesach Seder is held. They're saying Hallel and I've never heard that melody for Psalm 116. They start singing around 1:26:33 into the movie here https://youtu.be/J8EDp2xwaCg?t=5193

Does anyone know the tune? Where can I find more about it?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!